# How does vim capture keystrokes?

Tags: linux, vim

There are multiple questions that ask about capturing keystrokes, but the solutions provided have some complications.

ncurses termios structure/stty
-Changes the console settings so that SIGSTOP/SIGTERM would leave the setting in effect for the terminal.

X based solutions
-requires X server to be running(not that is is a huge problem, but it seems unnecessary to bring X server calls into a console application)

/dev/input/event*
-requires root

Vim seems to be able to capture keystrokes without root, an X server, and without changing the console settings. Does anyone know how vim is able to achieve this in linux?

Comment: Which action are you referring to, that you're surprised it can catch?

Comment: Do you have a real question on something specific? Did you look at Vim's source? Did you search/ask on the vim_dev mailing list?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm not sure what your are asking, I've rearranged the question to make it more clear. Perhaps this will help?

Comment: *Which* keystrokes are you interested in? After all, pressing `a` is not special in any way, shape or form, so why would you think Vim is performing magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at TTY raw mode -- there is a ioctl call which allows you to get individual keystrokes -- i.e. taking the tty out of line mode which is the default.

A quick search on `ioctl raw` give [this](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/_TTY_in_Raw_Mode.html) link which looks ok.

Comment: I believe that this does the same thing as the ncurses/stty raw solutions. The issue being that it will effect the terminal outside of the program.

Comment: Yes it will; you will have to use a signal handler to unset the setting when the program is paused/resumed and make sure you are setting the terminal back once the program exit.

Comment: I was missing the SIGCONT handler to change the settings back upon resume.